Rust, how to coerce a extern C function into any type to be able to call it?
I have the following function from the sqlite-vss Rust extension:
#[cfg(feature = "vector")]
#[link(name = "sqlite_vector0")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn sqlite3_vector_init();
}

I would like to load this extension into my sqlite instance using sqlx. Here one the maintainers has recommended to directly call the function by passing the parameters. The defined signature takes no parameters but it is meant to work as a regular sqlite extension, meaning one needs to pass the db pointer an error pointer-pointer and api routines pointer.
However, I don't know how can I coerce the function signature from the generated Rust code, so I can pass the raw pointers:
    let mut connection = pool.acquire().await?;
    let db_pointer = connection.lock_handle().await?;
    unsafe {
        sqlite3_vector_init( // expected 0 arguments, found 3
            db_pointer.as_raw_handle(),
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
        );
    }

What's the rust syntax to coerce the function call to anything that I can call?

Just declare it with the parameters.

It comes from a library, I cannot declare it with the parameters. But I see the question is a duplicate. Thanks anyways.

It doesn't matter what's in the header of the library. If the library expects some parameters, you can declare your function as taking them. No checks will be done against the header file (of course, you will get silent UB on mismatch).

yeah, but how do you do that? In the duplicated question they ended up using std::mem:transmute which is how I did it. Is it possible to re-declare it easily?

Easy, just change your declaration. extern "C" { pub fn sqlite3_vector_init(db: DbHandle, ...); }

I still don't get it. I tried re-declaring the extern C block inside my module but it fails with: symbol not found in flat namespace '_sqlite3_vector_init'. So I still don't understand what you mean with just re-declare the function

You need to include #[link(name)], just like with your current declaration.

Already tried, then it fails with a mangled name function
